# android load tab content before its selection

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am programmaticaly assigning tabs to tabHost properly. However, when starting the app and first tab is selected as default, for the other tabs, their content is not loaded until user press the tab. How to start loading its content without waiting until user selects it? thank you.

Comment: At the start of activity, initialize all the views at class that you are using for your tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ViewPager`'s [method offScreenPageLimit().](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit%28%29) It will load as many as you put in there.